# Gitlab and Gitlab CI CSRF error

Tags: csrf, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup gitlab with gitlab CI on internal network on Debian.
Im using Gitlab 6.7.3 abd gitlab ci 4.3.
Gitlab is on selfsigned ssl.

Everything seems ok until i try to start build. Both systems are connected and tokens auto setted up.

When i commit into repository the build shows in gitlab CI as "pending" and in log i can see:

```
Started POST "/projects/1/build?token=d18e0fea59ae4d40327f9cc11d2793" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-25 05:38:02 +0000
Processing by ProjectsController#build as HTML
  Parameters: {"before"=>"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "after"=>"437d8dddd2de6c3329ca58808fd08b4557f8b3af", "ref"=>"refs/heads/master", "user_id"=>3, "user_name"=>"Pokluda, Vaclav", "project_id"=>1, "repository"=>{"name"=>"test", "url"=>"git@mobile-gitlab.dev:Vaclav.Pokluda/test.git", "description"=>"", "homepage"=>"https://mobile-gitlab.dev/Vaclav.Pokluda/test"}, "commits"=>nil, "total_commits_count"=>0, "token"=>"d18e0fea59ae4d40327f9cc11d2793", "id"=>"1", "project"=>{}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 201 Created in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you may be hitting the same bug as me, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/761